# Does an http mutlipart request split up the file in multiple parts?

Tags: http, multipart

Does sending a file over http involve splitting up the file in multiple parts? I think that is not the case but could not find anything  conclusively written in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt about this. Is it guaranteed that the file would be received on the server in a single part?

Comment: When it comes to networking, nothing is ever guaranteed.  Connections can be aborted at any moment.  When the digger down the road takes out your fibre, it's gone.  Normally sending a file is done in 1 transfer.  It can also be done in many.

Comment: Thanks Adrien. My question pertains to HTTP layer. I am not concerned if its split up in layers below it.

Comment: Yes, that's the layer I was talking about.  Of course it is split at TCP/IP layer.  It may be split into multiple http requests. (Range header for partial downloads)

Comment: From my heuristic experience, a file that exceeds something like ~1kB is always splitt into multiple Parts. However, I have no Idea how the splitting algorithm is implemented and it's difficult to find anything useful about it online.